Using SQL Raw query to avoid Concurrency issues in EF Core
I have a question related to EF Core concurrency handling.
Let's assume we have an application that has a Person entity and it has balance property. and we have an add-balance controller endpoint that gets an input of personId and amount to add the balance.
If we use the traditional way that we track the person's entity from the database, set
person.Balance = person.Balance + amount

and then update the database with the new person entity it will cause concurrency conflicts as maybe other request came at the same time.
My question is, if I generated a SQL raw query to do this operation directly using RawSQLQuery
UPDATE Person SET Balance = Balance + {1} WHERE id = {2}

will this help me avoid concurrency problems on the application level? As now the database transaction handles all the values?
If not what should be the best approach to ensure that the person balance is updated correctly.

Yes it might get around those pesky "concurrency problems" at the application level - but it might also just simply overwrite data in the database that's been set by another user of your application, if the raw SQL doesn't check the same things (including the concurrency token - the ROWVERSION column in your table) as the EF Core generated SQL ....

thank you for your response @marc_s ,, but how the value will be overridden by the SQL? cuz im using SET Balance = Balance + {1}, so whatever value in the database it is incremented, I'm not using SET Balance = 50 for example I'm using SQL to increment on the SQL value.

Handling concurrency in an application is crucial to ensure data consistency, especially when multiple users or processes can modify the same data simultaneously. In Entity Framework (EF) Core, optimistic concurrency is the preferred approach. Let’s explore how you can handle concurrency conflicts effectively:

Optimistic Concurrency:


EF Core implements optimistic concurrency, which assumes that
concurrency conflicts are relatively rare.

Unlike pessimistic approaches that lock data upfront, optimistic concurrency doesn’t use locks. Instead, it checks if the data has changed since it was queried.

To implement optimistic concurrency, configure a property as a concurrency token. This token is loaded and tracked when an entity is queried.

When you perform an update or delete operation during SaveChanges(), EF Core compares the value of the concurrency token in the database with the original value read by EF Core.

For example, consider a Person entity with a Version property as a concurrency token:




public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Timestamp] // Concurrency token
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}




When you modify a Person instance and save changes, EF Core ensures that the Version remains consistent. If another request modified the same person, the update will fail, and you can handle the concurrency conflict accordingly.


Raw SQL Queries


Using raw SQL queries directly (like your UPDATE statement) bypasses EF Core’s tracking and concurrency mechanisms.

While it might work at the database level, it won’t prevent concurrency issues at the application level.

The database transaction doesn’t handle the values in the same way as EF Core’s change tracking


